# Floating text in revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, revision-history

I encounter this bug in [revision 3 and 4 of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21824402/revisions), though I think the bug should be reproducible on many other posts.

Using revision 4 as an example:

[image]

Take note of the vertical alignment of the same block of text in the right. It seems to have middle vertical alignment, though I couldn't find any rules in the CSS which could cause this problem.

Compared to a similar case [in this revision on Anime.SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2289/revisions), where the old style is still in effect and the comparison is displayed correctly:

[image]

I first encounter this problem on Firefox 36.0.1 and it is also reproducible on Chrome 40.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: *though I couldn't find any rules in the CSS which could cause this problem.* - yup, it's because it's missing the global `vertical-align:baseline;` rule that the previous theme had :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks as expected now after my Markdown diff alignment improvements that I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258959/115866).